# Заменить подстроку в строке.Си

Tags: c, алгоритм

Пока есть только проход по строке

```
while(j<M && (++i)<=N-M)
{
j=0;
while(j<M && s[i+j]==p[j])
j++;
}
```

Где p[M] - это длина подстрока 
s[N] - это сама строка

И ,например, в строке есть int i = 0;
Написанным выше алгоритмом нахожу перво попавшуюся i  .Как можно сделать так , чтобы заменить найденную подстроку на иные символы ?

Comment: Вроде есть еще strstr ,которая  возвращает указатель на найденный элемент , вот только не понятно, как им тут воспользоваться

Comment: Если заменяющая строка такой же длины, что и подстрока, найденная `strstr()`, то очень просто. Используйте [memcpy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy). `if ((p = strstr(string, substring))) memcpy(p, newsubstring, strlen(substring));` Конечно, все это более эффективно, если вы заранее знаете длину `substring` (тогда для поиска можно использовать [memmem](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmem.3.html))

Comment: Пример? Смотрите в ответе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Небольшой примерчик

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ uname -a; gcc --vers
Linux avp-ubu1 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
gcc.real (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$




#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char str[1000],
    subs[1000],
    repl[1000];

  puts("enter main string");
  if (!fgets(str, 1000, stdin))
    return 1;
  str[strlen(str) - 1] = 0; // kill \n

  while ((puts("enter substring and replace"),
          scanf("%s %s", subs, repl)) == 2) {
    size_t ssl = strlen(subs),
      rpl = strlen(repl),
      l = rpl < ssl ? rpl : ssl;
    if (rpl != ssl) {
      repl[l] = 0;
      subs[l] = 0;
      printf("warning, lenths are different:"
             " search <%s> and replace it to <%s>\n", subs, repl);
    }
    char *p = strstr(str, subs);
    if (p)
      memcpy(p, repl, l);
    printf("now str is: <%s>\n", str);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Что непонятно, спрашивайте.

Comment: да-да , я уже  сам догнал  тоже  вот , что  у меня вышло for(;;)
{
if ((p = strstr(A,"pass")))
{

 memcpy(p,"O4gh", strlen("pass"));
}
if(p==NULL)
  {
  break;
  }
  
}

Comment: @Elvin, молодец! Всегда лучше самому разобраться, а сюда заходить, чтобы посоветоваться, как сделать получше и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

```
 char str1[100] = {"blablabla000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"};//исходная
char str2[3] = {"bl"};//которую ищем
char str3[5] = {"dfgn"};//на что меняем
char str4[100]; //что получится


int h = 0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(str1); i = i + 1)
{
    if(str1[i] != str2[0])
    {
        str4[h] = str1[i];
        h = h + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        bool good_text = true;
        for(size_t j = 0; good_text && j < sizeof(str2) - 1; j = j + 1)
        {
            good_text = str1[i + j] == str2[j];
        }

        if(good_text)
        {
            for(size_t k = 0; k < sizeof(str3) - 1; k++)
            {
                str4[h] = str3[k];
                h = h + 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            str4[h] = str1[i];
            h = h + 1;
        }
    }
}

printf(str4);
```

Comment: А разве можно применять sizeof на символьные строки ?